# Understanding the CreateUser method of MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

In the following method which comes from MembershipUser class

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, 
                                          string email,
                                          string passwordQuestion,
                                          string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, 
                                          object providerUserKey,
                                          out MembershipCreateStatus status)
```

can anyone explain me what are following for?

```
 bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status
```

I looked up at the following site from microsoft [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152012.aspx) but I couldn't understand properly.

Comment: What exactly can't you understand? That documentation seems fairly straightforward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that documentation:

```
isApproved
Type: System.Boolean
A Boolean that indicates whether the new user is approved to log on.
providerUserKey
Type: System.Object
The user identifier for the user that should be stored in the membership data store.
status
Type: System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus
A MembershipCreateStatus indicating that the user was created successfully or the reason creation failed.
```

It seems quite straightforward to me. You could pass `isApproved: false` to the method if you wanted a user to be created without the ability to log on.

Looking at the [documentation for MembershipCreateStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus.aspx) you can see that this will return a variety of different error messages specifying exactly why the user creation failed (or was successful).

As for the `providerUserKey`, this should be a value to uniquely identify a user, such as an integer id.